# PostgreSQL multiple criteria statement

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the following postgreSQL statement that returns dates that school is open and attendance needs to be taken

```
SELECT school_date 
FROM attendance_calendar 
WHERE syear='$syear' 
AND school_date<CURRENT_DATE 
AND calendar_id='$cal_ID'
```

I then have another table called attendance_completed which has a column called school_date that i want to query for each returned date from the above statement. But instead of doing two different statements, just wondering if someone can help combine the statement?

Basically, i would like the above statement to check if the returned school_date exists in the table called attendance_completed, and only return the dates that are missing.

Thanks

Comment: these are the columns i have in the two tables
attendance_calendar:
syear
school_date
calendar_id 

attendance_completed:
school_date
class_id

calender_id needs to equal $cal_ID and class_id needs to equal $class_ID which i already have defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT cal.school_date
FROM attendance_calendar cal
WHERE  cal.school_date NOT IN (
    SELECT com.school_date
    FROM attendance_completed com
    WHERE com.school_date IS NOT NULL
) AND
cal.syear = '$syear' AND
cal.school_date < CURRENT_DATE AND
cal.calendar_id = '$cal_ID;
```