# Is it possible that LEFT JOIN fails while subquery with NOT IN clause suceeds?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, in-clause, notin

A while I have posted an answer to this question [PostgreSQL multiple criteria statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686107/postgresql-multiple-criteria-statement/18686388).

Task was quite simple - select values from one table if there is no corresponding value in another table. Assuming we have tables like below:

```
CREATE TABLE first  (foo numeric);
CREATE TABLE second (foo numeric);
```

we would like to get all the values from `first.foo` which doesn’t occur in the `second.foo`. I've proposed two solutions:

- using `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
SELECT first.foo
FROM first
LEFT JOIN  second 
ON first.foo = second.foo
WHERE second.foo IS NULL;
```

- combining subquery and `IN` operator:

```
SELECT first.foo 
FROM first
WHERE first.foo NOT IN (
  SELECT second.foo FROM second
);
```

For some reason the first wouldn't work (returned 0 rows) in the context of the OP and it has been bugging me since then. I've tried to reproduce that issue using different versions of PostgreSQL but no luck so far.

Is there any particular reason why the first solution would fail and the second worked as expected? Am I missing something obvious?

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e8fdc/1) is sqlfiddle but it seems to work on any available platform.

**Edit**

Like @bma and @MostyMostacho pointed out in the comments it should be rather second one that returned no results ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/aa812/1)).

Answer (score 2):

As per your sql fiddle, your NOT IN query fails to return results because of the NULL in the second table.

The problem is that NULL means "UNKNOWN" and therefore we cannot say that the following expression is true:  `10 not in (5, null)`.

The reason is what happens when 10 = NULL is compared.   We get a NULL back, not a true.  This means that a NULL in the NOT IN clause means that no rows will ever pass.

To get the second one to perform the way you expect you have a relatively convoluted query:

```
SELECT first.foo 
FROM first
WHERE (first.foo  IN (
  SELECT second.foo FROM second
) IS NOT TRUE);
```

This will properly handle the NULL comparisons, but the join syntax is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

`select values from one table if there is no corresponding value in another table.` You just answered your own question:

```
SELECT o.value
FROM table_one o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_two t
    WHERE t.value = o.value
    );
```

---

A short demonstration:

```
CREATE TABLE first  (foo numeric);
CREATE TABLE second (foo numeric);

INSERT INTO first VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (NULL); -- added this for completeness

INSERT INTO second VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO second VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO second VALUES (NULL);


SELECT f.foo AS ffoo, s.foo AS sfoo
        -- these expressions all yield boolean values
        , (f.foo = s.foo)                                               AS is_equal
        , (f.foo IN (SELECT foo FROM second))                           AS is_in
        , (f.foo NOT IN (SELECT foo FROM second))                       AS is_not_in
        , (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM second x WHERE x.foo = f.foo))         AS does_exist
        , (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM second x WHERE x.foo = f.foo))     AS does_not_exist
        , (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM first x LEFT JOIN second y ON x.foo = y.foo
                WHERE x.foo = f.foo AND y.foo IS NULL))
                                                                        AS left_join_is_null
FROM first f
FULL JOIN second s ON (f.foo = s.foo AND (f.foo IS NOT NULL OR s.foo IS NOT NULL) )
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
 ffoo | sfoo | is_equal | is_in | is_not_in | does_exist | does_not_exist | left_join_is_null 
------+------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------------
    1 |    1 | t        | t     | f         | t          | f              | f
    2 |      |          |       |           | f          | t              | t
    3 |    3 | t        | t     | f         | t          | f              | f
    4 |      |          |       |           | f          | t              | t
    5 |      |          |       |           | f          | t              | t
      |      |          |       |           | f          | t              | f
      |      |          |       |           | f          | t              | f
(7 rows)
```

As you can see, the boolean can be NULL for the `IN()` and *equals* cases.
It cannot be NULL for the `EXISTS()` case. To be or not to be.
The `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE s.foo IS NULL` is (almost) equivalent to the NOT EXISTS case, except that it actually includes `second.*` into the query results (which is not needed, in most cases)